# Extract list of values from array given coordinate list

Tags: matlab, matrix, coordinate

I have a large 2D matrix, `A` (8192x10201) and a list of coordinates, `coord` (3622x2). I am trying to find the value of the array at each index and put it into a 1D list.

I could use the following `for` loop, but I was wondering if there was a more elegant solution.

```
data = [];
for ii = 1:numel(coord(:,1))
    data = [data; A(coord(ii,1), coord(ii,2)];
end
```

EDIT: Things I have tested:

1.`data = A(coord)`

`data` is a 3622x2 matrix. I'm not certain how the values in `data` relate to the coordinates in `coord`.

2.`data = A(coord(:,1), coord(:,2))`

`data` is 3622x3622 matrix. I am very much uncertain of how it relates to 'coord'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way:

```
A(sub2ind(size(A), coord(:, 1), coord(:, 2)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Yet another way:

```
A(coord(:, 1) + (coord(:, 2)-1)*size(A,1))
```

Comment: This *should* be equivalent to the `sub2ind` answer, but I bet `sub2ind` does all sorts of checking of input arguments that will make it slower.

Answer (score 0):

I'd think `data = A(coord)` should do it. If not, `data = A(coord(:,1),cord(:,2))` surely will. I can't test right now, so something might me slipping my mind.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following:

```
diag(A(coord(:,1),coord(:,2)))
```

Comment: This is a very expensive way of accomplishing the task. Check the upvoted answer, `sub2ind` is the correct way to do it.

Comment: OK. I'll try the other method later and mark it as correct after testing. Thanks for letting me know @CrisLuengo

Comment: @CrisLuengo, Thanks for pointing out the extreme slowness of my original answer, which I was totally oblivious to! I submitted another answer that seems to be faster than the others during testing.

Comment: Just an explanation: this retrieves N^2 elements from A, then keeps only N of them. It creates a (potentially) large intermediate matrix that is not necessary.